# How to check for NAs and equality at the same time

Tags: r

I have 2 columns of a data frame that looks like this

```
   1   NA
   NA  2
   2   5 
   3   NA
   NA  NA
```

How would I return the rows in which both of the values are less than 3 or are NA? The output would look like:

```
   1   NA
   NA  2
   NA  NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to `replace` the `NA` with a value that the intended value, do a `rowSums` on the logical matrix and convert it to a logical vector for subsetting rows

```
df1[rowSums(replace(df1, is.na(df1), 2) < 3) == 2,]
#  v1 v2
#1  1 NA
#2 NA  2
#5 NA NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c(1L, NA, 2L, 3L, NA), v2 = c(NA, 2L, 5L, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I think the logic I was trying to execute was to both check for NAs and being under a threshold for multiple columns so I don't think this would work.

Comment: @counterproductiveola  Can you try the updated code

Comment: Same idea: `df1[rowMeans(df1 < 3, na.rm = T) == 1, ]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` and then test if either all are `NA` or all are `<3`.

```
x <- read.table(text="1   NA
   NA  2
   2   5 
   3   NA
   NA  NA")

x[apply(x, 1, function(y) {all(is.na(y)) || all(y[!is.na(y)]<3)}),]
#  V1 V2
#1  1 NA
#2 NA  2
#5 NA NA
```

Or see the comment from @kath simpler as:

```
x[apply(x, 1, function(y) {all(y < 3, na.rm = TRUE)}),]
```

Or a variant:

```
x[apply(x, 1, function(y) {all(y[!is.na(y)] < 3)}),]
```

Comment: You can replace the function by  `all(y < 3, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @kath Oh yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably more complex than it should, but works:

```
a = c(1, NA, 2, 3, NA)
b = c(NA, 2, 5, NA, NA)

list.ab = as.data.frame(list(a = a, b = b))

list.rows = c()
for (x in 1:nrow(list.ab)) {
  row = list.ab[x, ]
  nas = sum(is.na(row))
  lowerthan3 = sum(row < 3, na.rm = T)
  total.conds = nas + lowerthan3
  if (total.conds == 2) {
    list.rows = c(list.rows, x)
  }
}

print(list.ab[list.rows, ])

   a  b
1  1 NA
2 NA  2
5 NA NA
```